# What to do with a question that is no longer relevant?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closing, deletion

Refer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2790102/) I asked a little while ago.

I thought I spotted a mistake in a textbook, but actually I made a mistake myself when I tried to write a counterexample. There is no longer a mistake I spot. The whole question is no longer relevant.

Should we close the question or should I delete the question? I think deleting the question does not tell the people who are trying to help me if I have solved my problems so I am personally against deleting the question. If the question should be closed, which reason should I use to close the question?

By the way, if it should be closed, please help me close the question.

Comment: I think what you've done (voting to close as no longer relevant) is okay; there are currently no answers posted so not much effort has been wasted.

Comment: Closing is right in this case. If in the future you ask a question and then discover an interesting answer and think the question/answer combination may be of use to someone in the future of the future you can answer your own question, and accept your answer. Then the question won't linger on the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should just delete it. There is no reason to clog up the site with questions that don't need to be answered. The localized nature of your mistake also makes it unlikely that the question will be useful for future users. It is nice that you are concerned with the efforts of those helping you, but no answer was posted, and comments are intended to be transient on SE.